# Using BeginInvoke method on a different machine or OS

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin.android, delegation

As I have known and read, most of the concepts about multi thread programming are directly related to the the machine and the OS of the device which is being used. The reason is that the different OSs which are run on different machines have different approaches about threads.

As you now in C# we can execute a method asynchronously using `BeginInvoke` of it's appropriate delegation. This can be very odd because this mechanism is still accessible when I code in a xamarin(android) project although the ultimate machine and OS will be ARM7 and Android respectively! Does it really work in this situation? What I am trying to say is, I think it must work only on X86 and windows. Is it wrong?

Comment: What makes you believe that `BeginInvoke` is OS and CPU architecture specific?

Comment: Isn't it? I think the mechanism of the spawning threads are totally different on different OS @mjwills

Comment: They are, but BeginInvoke is an abstraction over the underlying threading model. .Net / Mono manage the complexity for you.